# Change grad school and get accepted. Worry that no prof in the new university wants to work with me

Tags: graduate-admissions, supervision

My supervisor and I are not a good match and there is no one in my department has the same interest. Therefore, I applied to a new university in my second year of Ph.D. and got accepted even though I did not have any LORs from my current university. Now the problem which I am worrying is that I will be looked down by the faculty in the new university. They might not be interested in working with a student who changed grad school. Even I get accepted, but if no one wants to work with me, So how I am going to get PhD?

Comment: Did you hide in your more recent applications that you are currently a PhD student at another institution? Or did your application make that fact clear?

Comment: I make it clear that I am currently a PhD student

Comment: That's good. Then I strongly support the answer by @aeismail.

Answer (score 9):

Your admission to the new school was decided upon by members of the faculty of the department to which you applied. So it's unlikely that you'd have been admitted without there being at least one or two people in the new department who think you'd fit in and would therefore be interested in working with you.

If you still have doubts, there is an easy way to answer the question. Just ask the professors you're interested in working with if they are likely to have positions available when you arrive, and if they'd be willing to consider you for them.